# Passing this from .call() to arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have an arrow function that I am trying to execute with `call()`. For the sake of simplification, as follows:

**Operational as expected**

```
const func = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
}

func.call(null, e)
```

**Hmm ... what's going on here?**

I would expect the following code to pass `element` into `func` as `this`.

```
const func = (e) => {
    console.log(this)
    console.log(e)
}

func.call(element, e)
```

But, instead `this` remains `undefined`.

If I switch it to a regular function definition, all works as expected.

```
const func = function (e) {
    console.log(this)
    console.log(e)
}

func.call(element, e)
```

**Question**

Why am I not able to pass a context for `this` into an arrow function from `call()`?

Comment: Out of interest, why did you decide to use an arrow function instead of a regular function?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue No reason, purely experimentation where I noticed this behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`this` is not bound in arrow functions, so `call()` and `apply()` can only pass in parameters. `this` is ignored

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Invoked_through_call_or_apply

Comment: Great innit, and then eslint says it's got an issue with all function() and to use arrow ones. So where we had a let root = this; solution we now have a, Oh look we can't use call or apply now.  Unless you remove the check from eslint for function, but airbnb lint is set to warn about functions.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has [lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Lexical_scoping) meaning value of `this` inside arrow function would be same as that outside of arrow function. In pre-ES6 form `this` is the object that you passed as a first argument to `call` method.