# Call, Apply & Bind still gives 'undefined' for 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, this

Please see the code below:

```
let xy = {name:"matt", age: 44};
let greetFunc = nickName => "Hello " + nickName + ". Your age is " + this.age + " now";
console.log(greetFunc.call(xy, "vms"));
```

The result is:

```
Hello vms. Your age is undefined now
```

Why is 'this.age' returning 'undefined'? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't seem like a duplicate. the linked question and answers don't go into any depth about the `.call` method

Comment: @worc: What more than *"Arrow functions don't have their own `this` or `arguments` binding."* and *"Note that this also means that is not possible to set an arrow function's `this` with `.bind` or `.call`."* (from my answer) do you expect? Which information is missing for you?

Comment: it's buried in the answer. it's nice that there's a comprehensive wiki answer there, but that seems like a poor substitution for just answering the question

Comment: i think the problem i'm seeing here is linking to a dense, comprehensive answer is more RTFM than anything especially useful or welcoming

Comment: @worc: Then you might prefer this question , which was also closed as duplicate but has a short answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43062732/218196

Comment: yeah! that's a super concise answer.

Comment: I see. Arrow functions are not equivalent to function declarations/expressions. Thanks.